# List of categories and cms pages in single widget instance

Tags: category, cms, widgets, widget

need a bit of advice with widget instance's.

I need to great a widget instance which lists both cms pages and categories which the client can change easily. here is what it needs to look like:

[image: cat/cms list]

Now any of these links can be CMS or category pages, whichever the client decides they want, hence why i would ideally be a widget instance

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

A widget within a widget? If so how would i do that?

I have build custom widgets so i pretty much understand that process, so any advice is welcome

Thanks